# WiFi7 routers and spatial streams

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

It is my understanding that the number of spatial streams supported by a WiFi device is limited to the number of antennas. I am looking at two WiFi7 routers below that have 8 antennas each, but both claim to support 12 streams? Is there something I am missing?

https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-be800/#overview

https://www.netgear.com/home/wifi/routers/rs700s/

Comment: Can you tell us how you came to the understanding that the spatial streams are limited to the number of antennae?

Comment: Question for close-voter… In what way is this a hardware req?

Comment: I look at spatial streams as a MIMO concept and for a n x n MIMO operation, my assumption is that only one stream of data can be sent from each antenna, so the device is limited to n streams. Maybe my assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Given some advertising speak from a router box versus assumptions reached without data, I don't know which I'd believe, except... Someone can get sued for writing provably false things on a box they sell. So, I'm guessing that you are wrong. I'm also guessing that information is documented somewhere. What research have you done regarding this?

Comment: It is possible that the 8 antennas are actually dual/tri band, so there are >12 antenna elements and that's how 12 streams are being supported. Not sure if there is anyone on this forum who can confirm that this is how wifi router spatial streams work in general.